# How to upload only .psd in php file upload

Tags: php, html, input, tags

I am trying to restrict file upload to images only in the php but does not allow me to upload .psd format of images. how to allow [.](http://siteflu.com)psd file upload in the php.

Right now I'm doing this way 
 `<input accept="image/*" type="file" name="image" />`

Comment: client side verifications are useless.

Answer (score 3):

Never rely on client side verification's and **do not trust** `$_FILES['upfile']['mime']` value!!

You need to check the following mime types for `psd` files, with some modification to fit your case:

```
            'psd' => 'image/psd',
            'psd' => 'image/x-photoshop',
            'psd' => 'application/photoshop',
            'psd' => 'zz-application/zz-winassoc-psd',
            'psd' => 'application/psd'
```

---

From the php manual [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#features.file-upload) :

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['image']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['image']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['image']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['image']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['image']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'psd' => 'image/psd',
            'psd' => 'image/x-photoshop',
            'psd' => 'application/photoshop',
            'psd' => 'zz-application/zz-winassoc-psd',
            'psd' => 'application/psd'
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['image']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }

    echo 'File is uploaded successfully.';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```